# Does Kyoukai no Kanata anime adapt light novel closely?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

I watched the *Kyoukai no Kanata* anime. So I was wondering if the anime adapted the light novel closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the story is different from around episode 3 onwards, because the light novels were still being written while the anime was being produced

I've only read the fan translation of the first one and a half volume and as far as I know the entire hollow shadow thing wasn't even in the light novels.

Also, the Mirai-hen movie with the amnesia was anime original.